# Android HelloWorld not loading in AVD, loading all API samples

Tags: android, android-emulator

Just started with the Android SDK and followed the HelloWord application but it will not load in the emulator.

I created the project with the platform 3.0 api level 11 (3/11), then recreated the project using 2.3.3/10.

The emulator just does not start. In a whole day, I was able to see the home screen only once for 2 seconds before it crashed. Also, in that instance the emulator took really long to load (30 minutes)

When I installed the SDK I also downloaded the samples for the SDK API's 10/11.
Observing the LogCat in the DDMS view, I realized every time I try to Run a project, those sample apps get loaded.

I have now created yet another project, this time using 1.5/3 and it works.

- **I'm assuming the sample app's are one reason why it takes the emulator so long to load?**
- **Perhaps also is why    the HelloWorld
  won't load, or why the    emulator
  crashes often?**
- **Is there any way to prevent those apps to be loaded?**

Usually, when running either the 10/11 api level projects the emulator either crashes or times-out. The console would read:

```
[2011-04-22 15:45:44 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-04-22 15:45:44 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-22 15:45:44 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.skinnygeek.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-04-22 15:45:44 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'g_AVD2'
[2011-04-22 15:45:44 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-04-22 15:45:44 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2011-04-22 15:46:00 - HelloAndroid] Success!
[2011-04-22 15:46:01 - HelloAndroid] Starting activity com.skinnygeek.android.HelloAndroid on device emulator-5554
```

or

```
[2011-04-22 16:19:13 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-04-22 16:19:13 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-04-22 16:19:13 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.skinnygeek.android.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-04-22 16:19:13 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'g_AVD2'
[2011-04-22 16:19:13 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-04-22 16:19:26 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554': timeout
```

Comment: no idea, but from what i've seen of honeycomb in the emulator, i would say it's just the emulator. honeycomb can barely run in the emulator.

Comment: @ Darren Kopp ok, I will keep that in mind. It would be nice to get someone to confirm that, thou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Honeycomb image on the emulator is really^4 slow.  There's a reason these 3.0 tablets are running a Tegra2 and the performance of the emulator suggests why.  Unless you need to specifically test features of Honeycomb, I suggest developing and testing your apps on an emulator image running platform level 10 or earlier.